# cross-account SNS publishing with HTTPS Endpoint: how to identify originating account?

Tags: publish, amazon-sns, account

How to deal with messages when they are forwarded through another account?

I want several accounts to publish their SNS-messages through a single SNS-Topic in a central account within the same region. The subscription will be a HTTPS Endpoint. On the origin account I have several services (such like: Cloudwatch Event, Systems Manager, ...) for message publishing. For later processing purposes I want to identify (preferably by AccountId) the originating AWS Account which produced the message.
Usually a SNS json message looks [like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-unsubscribe-confirmation-json). Based on the documentation I can't see how to figure out which eventually another account created the message. Do you have an idea how this will work or do you have examples?

So how can I achieve this?

```
Message from Account1 to \
                          SNS-Topic Account-Central -> HTTPS-Endpoint -> Parsing JSON Message (Message comes from Account1 ???)
Message from Account2 to /
```

Comment: Does the message include an ARN? You can extract the AWS Account from the ARN.

Comment: Notification JSON-Format of course contains an ARN, but this is the ARN from the SNS-Topic, which belongs to the "sending" Account. This is not what I want. I need some information about the "producing" account behind the  "sending" account.

Comment: Are those "sending" services sending a message to SNS in their own account, which is then forwarding the message to SNS in a central account, or are they all just independently sending a message to the central SNS topic? If the latter, then I guess you'd want to view details of the "sender", which isn't part of the message itself. I haven't seen a way to retrieve information about who sent a message to SNS. I guess if the original message doesn't contain an identifier, then it will be difficult. You might need to send to a "local" SNS topic first, then have it forward on the message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by evaluating the sns `Message` attribute itself. In my particular case i received forwarded Cloudwatch Events which I wanted to map to the originating account. I json-decoded the message attribute and resolved the account from the `account` attribute.

example sns_data:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "b51e31b6-257b-5e63-bf40-678c64816bb6",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678:mytopic",
  "Message" : "{\"version\":\"0\",\"id\":\"06498297-40cc-8bad-6b7d-20a1142a3162\",\"detail-type\":\"EC2 Instance State-change Notification\",\"source\":\"aws.ec2\",\"account\":\"987654321\",\"time\":\"2019-11-04T15:11:53Z\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"resources\":[\"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:987654321:instance/i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"],\"detail\":{\"instance-id\":\"i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"state\":\"running\"}}",
  "Timestamp" : "2019-11-04T15:11:54.002Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "f9dLWFByoErZvtKOWi9f8qk+c2sHH1faltwEi8AeeC76j2kHGJiGbaPh5+XfnECtmRjICHv3shIho02f7lDEvuxrq2tVmL8Je9+eCZhbN1uv3TIxZFfMYIzMTvGEqVaVr2XclFJbqlbb1OpYkvCf64HI6+YHlzT2HFg7O7n3qii4iRQ1Lx8yR6ipneDoM4S5H91J1vZT9jczjXjOStDnApJiAsrULCSrTIUWSrGdd45wwn+Vf4waNhKPKHskodVYXVmKvpdRB1ZZn/dne0Q4y/fWhtyPCPhw0oGiGQax4BxoDgwf60zy8FAIAdWF0LNRM6ZvVaHZOdTsvoJEVQ5Ttg==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-6aad65c2f9911b05cd53efda11f913f9.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678:mytopic:308e8a6f-0935-4f8b-b1fd-31484d7b0e8e"
}
```

Python3 Code for json parsing and resolving account:

```
print(json.loads(json.loads(sns_data)['Message'])['account'])
```